# Adding class for expanded rows in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have created a table following this codepen to allow for expandable rows:
https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/expanding

I would like to add a class to just the expanded rows to change the background color and remove borders. I saw that you could change the style of the toggle element, but I wasn't able to find a way to target the expanded rows and add a class to the cells/rows. Do you know if there is a way to add a class to just the expanded rows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Row Properties](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGroupBy#row-properties), there is an attribute for every row called "depth". Depth grows by 1 for each sub-row layer, so you can style based on the depth layer by checking a row's depth while you iterate over it; i.e,

```
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            
            let s = { backgroundColor: 'red' }
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()} style={row.depth === 1 ? s : {}}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()} >{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
```

colors all sub-rows with a depth of 1 to red.